# CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException

Tags: c#, android, .net, api, xamarin

I am getting the following error on my Xamarin.Forms project:

```
  at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException () [0x00010] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested () [0x00008] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0004f] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:343 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x000e4] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:393 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00285] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:286 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in <814c177e4f174da89876fafdde15d02e>:0 
  at BUCOLogin.Constants.RestService.GetBranchesAsync (System.String uri) [0x00047] in C:\VST\BFR Login\Login\Constants\RestService.cs:23 }
```

After some investigation it seems that a token is being cancelled, but I'm not sure where this token is located or even why its being cancelled. I am using an open API request with no APIKey needed :

Constants.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace BUCOLogin.Constants
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public const string OpenBabbageEndpoint = "http://IP/ILDTEST/XI/Core/GetBranches";
        //public const string OpenBabbageAPIKey = "f6a04a6c3fbc534c295f6a5e8548e0f6";
    }
}
```

When stepping through code, it stalls/waits for a while at the following code before giving me the exception:

```cs
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This code is located in RestService.cs :

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace BUCOLogin.Constants
{
    public class RestService
    {
        HttpClient _client;

        public RestService()
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async Task<GetBranches> GetBranchesAsync(string uri)
        {
            GetBranches branchesData = null;
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    branchesData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetBranches>(content);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }

            return branchesData;
        }
    }
}
```

GetBranches.cs :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace BUCOLogin.Constants
{
    public class GetBranches
    {

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("postcode")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("manager")]
        public string Manager { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("open")]
        public string Open { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("close")]
        public string Close { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("opensat")]
        public string Opensat { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("closesat")]
        public string Closesat { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The uri Request does bring back a result on Postman so I am not sure why I am getting this exception and how to move forward.

Thanks in advance.

#### UPDATE

After Updating the RestService.cs with @Nkosi code, I get the following error :

```
{System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
  at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException () [0x00010] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested () [0x00008] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0004f] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:343 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x000e4] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:393 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00285] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:286 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in <814c177e4f174da89876fafdde15d02e>:0 
  at BUCOLogin.Constants.RestService.GetBranchesAsync (System.String uri) [0x00046] in C:\Visual Studio Training\BUCO FR Login\FacialRecognitionLogin\Constants\RestService.cs:18 }
```

#### UPDATE 2

After adding `_client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);` :

```
{Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /IP (port 791) from /IP (port 60644) after 86400000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) ---> Android.Systems.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <dec6115f7d4449ee8ce1bcacaa8cb579>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <dec6115f7d4449ee8ce1bcacaa8cb579>:0 
  at Java.Net.HttpURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x00000] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-28/mcw/Java.Net.HttpURLConnection.cs:714 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0005a] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:344 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x000e4] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:393 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00285] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/src/Mono.Android/Xamarin.Android.Net/AndroidClientHandler.cs:286 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in <814c177e4f174da89876fafdde15d02e>:0 
  at BUCOLogin.Constants.RestService.GetBranchesAsync (System.String uri) [0x00066] in C:\Visual Studio Training\BUCO FR Login\FacialRecognitionLogin\Constants\RestService.cs:21 
  --- End of managed Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException stack trace ---
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /IP (port 791) from /IP (port 60644) after 86400000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:276)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:187)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:231)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:145)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:141)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:267)
    ... 18 more
}
```

Comment: Can you try increasing `_client.Timeout`?

Comment: Are you making any blocking calls higher up in the call stack

Comment: If it's an Android, I think there is restriction for raw `http` requests. If it's not secure, could you try to setup self validated `ssl context`?

Comment: @Kahbazi - increased the Timeout to 300 seconds and now I am getting a SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace

Comment: @Kahbazi - Added in question.

Comment: Are you sure that your device have access to the destination ip/port?

Comment: @Kahbazi - double checked with client and your suspicion was correct. The wifi they provided did not have access to the ip/port. Switched to the correct wifi and I am now starting to see attempts on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try increasing `HttpClient.Timeout` to avoid `OperationCanceledException`.

and for

> Java.Net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /IP (port 791)
>   from /IP (port 60644) after 86400000ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT
>   (Connection timed out) ---> Android.Systems.ErrnoException:
>   isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

make sure that your device has network access to the IP/port that it's connecting to.